# Mix two sql queries: return what's requested in the first one but ignoring the second one

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, inner-join

I have two queries which work properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MarcadaProduccio.Article, 
                SUM(MarcadaProduccio.Rendiment * MarcadaProduccio.HoresMarcada)/SUM(MarcadaProduccio.HoresMarcada) AS MitjanaPonderada 
FROM MarcadaProduccio 
INNER JOIN MarcadaProduccio ON ParosMarcadesProduccio.IDMarcada = MarcadaProduccio.ID
WHERE   MarcadaProduccio.Article IN (SELECT DISTINCT MarcadaProduccio.Article FROM MarcadaProduccio) 
GROUP BY MarcadaProduccio.Article

SELECT ParosMarcadesProduccio.IDMarcada 
FROM ParosMarcadesProduccio 
WHERE ParosMarcadesProduccio.DescripcioParo LIKE "%MONTAJE%"
```

What I would like is to do one query which SELECTs as requested in the first query but ignoring the rows returned by the second query when ParosMarcadesProduccio.IDMarcada = MarcadaProduccio.ID.

How do I do that?

Thank you

PD: Structure of the tables MarcadaProduccio and ParosMarcadesProduccio

[image: Main table]
[image: Aux table]

Answer (score 1):

Your first query cannot work, because `ParosMarcadaProduccio` is not defined.  You can simplify the query to something like this:

```
SELECT mp.Article, SUM(mp.Rendiment * mp.HoresMarcada) / SUM(mp.HoresMarcada) AS MitjanaPonderada 
FROM MarcadaProduccio mp INNER JOIN
     ParosMarcadaProduccio pmp
     ON pmp.IDMarcada = mp.ID
WHERE mp.Article IN (SELECT mp2.Article FROM MarcadaProduccio mp2) 
GROUP BY mp.Article;
```

Note that the `SELECT DISTINCT`s are not needed.

```
SELECT mp.Article, SUM(mp.Rendiment * mp.HoresMarcada) / SUM(mp.HoresMarcada) AS MitjanaPonderada 
FROM MarcadaProduccio mp INNER JOIN
     ParosMarcadaProduccio pmp
     ON pmp.IDMarcada = mp.ID
WHERE mp.Article IN (SELECT mp2.Article FROM MarcadaProduccio mp2) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT pmp.IDMarcada
                  FROM ParosMarcadaProduccio pmp2
                  WHERE pmp2.DescripcioParo LIKE '%MONTAJE%' AND
                        pmp.IDMarcada = mp.id
                 )
GROUP BY mp.Article;
```

When learning to use subqueries for filtering, I strongly recommend `NOT EXISTS` over `NOT IN`.  The latter behaves strangely when the subquery returns `NULL` values.  You might as well learn the better way first.

Comment: If I try the first option, it doesn't work. I tried isolating one option: SELECT mp.Article,mp.Rendiment, mp.HoresMarcada, SUM(mp.Rendiment * mp.HoresMarcada) / SUM(mp.HoresMarcada) AS MitjanaPonderada 
FROM MarcadaProduccio mp INNER JOIN
     ParosMarcadesProduccio pmp
     ON pmp.IDMarcada = mp.ID
WHERE mp.Article LIKE "%one_specific_article%"  but it only returns one row. Not the sum/average of them. The second option returns 0 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following approach using `NOT IN`, just make sure that the `ParosMarcadesProduccio.IDMarcada` is never `NULL`.

```
SELECT MarcadaProduccio.ID, MarcadaProduccio.Article, 
       SUM(MarcadaProduccio.Rendiment * MarcadaProduccio.HoresMarcada)/SUM(MarcadaProduccio.HoresMarcada) AS MitjanaPonderada 
FROM MarcadaProduccio 
INNER JOIN MarcadaProduccio ON ParosMarcadesProduccio.IDMarcada = MarcadaProduccio.ID
WHERE   MarcadaProduccio.Article IN (SELECT DISTINCT MarcadaProduccio.Article FROM MarcadaProduccio) and
        MarcadaProduccio.ID NOT IN (
           --your second query
           SELECT ParosMarcadesProduccio.IDMarcada 
           FROM ParosMarcadesProduccio 
           WHERE ParosMarcadesProduccio.DescripcioParo LIKE "%MONTAJE%"             
        )
GROUP BY MarcadaProduccio.ID, MarcadaProduccio.Article
```

**EDIT:** as noted by others, `DISTINCT` seems suspicious in your query and it should be probably removed.

Comment: if you ever find yourself with GROUP BY and DISTINCT in the same query, you can rest assured that something's not quite right somewhere.

Comment: @Strawberry true, I have removed it